# Allowed narrowing from integer to char in C++

Tags: c++

The complier treats a literal of the form 1, 2, 24, 264 as type int.

In the initializer list of declaring there is no narrowing allowed.

```
char c4 {24};
char c5 {264}; // error
```

How come the first is accepted but not the second line?

Comment: Because the compiler knows that the literal value will not fit in 8 bits.

Comment: By that logic int x4 {2.0}; should be allowed but is not.

Comment: @shreyasva: It's a lossy conversion. Both cases here are almost certainly a programmer error.  The double to int example is not the same thing.